# Bi-invariant form on compact connected Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\omega$ be a left invariant $k$-form, how to prove that  $r^*_a \omega$ is left invariant?
What I do:

$(l^*_g (r^*_a \omega))_x (v_1, \ldots,v_k)=(r^*_a \omega))_{gx} ({l_g}_*v_1, \ldots,{l_g}_*v_k)= \omega_{gxa} ({r_a}_* {l_g}_*v_1, \ldots,{r_a}_* {l_g}_*v_k)=$

and stuck here...

The right side of the equality should be $(r^*_a \omega)_x(v_1, \ldots,v_k)$.

Comment: Notice that $r_al_g=l_gr_a$.

Comment: thanks, the result follow!

Comment: taking advantage of the topic, I'd like to ask another question: We have $r^*_a \omega = f(a)\omega$ how to prove that this $f$ defines a homomorphism of groups? ($G$ into the multiplicative reals)

Comment: Simply use the definition!

Comment: I used, we obviously must have $r^*_{ab}\omega=f(a)f(b)\omega$, so I tried to develop the left side, but I stuck...

Comment: you are not using the fact that $r_{ab}^*\omega=f(ab)\omega$

Comment: I don't know how to use this result...

Comment: hint: $r_{ab}=r_b \circ r_a$

Comment: Many people may want to read your question... not only the experts. You could be nicer and define $r_a^*$ and this sort of stuff, so the rest of us can learn from your post as well.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez  hi i have a question. does $\omega$ need to be a top left invariant form for  $f$ to be a homomorphism or is it sufficient that $\omega$ is a top form?